# In Angular, how do you increment a counter in the view?

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-include

For instance, I want have a counter in a recursive script that counts how many times the script has been called.

However, instead of getting a printout of

```
1
2
3
...
```

I'm getting

```
1
1
1
...
```

Here's my template code:

```
 <div ng-app="App" ng-controller="ctrl">
     <div>
         <div ng-include="'temp.html'" onload="counter=counter"></div>
     </div>

     <script type="text/ng-template" id="temp.html">
        <h3> {{counter+1}} </h3>
         <div ng-include="'temp.html'" onload="counter=counter"></div>
    </script>
</div>
```

Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tp2tuwyy/1/

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Update HTMl as follow

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="ctrl">
     <div>
        <div ng-include="'temp.html'" onload="counter=counter"></div>
     </div>

     <script type="text/ng-template" id="temp.html">
         <h3> {{counter}} </h3>
         <div ng-include="'temp.html'" onload="counter=counter+1"></div>
     </script>
</div>
```

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Just update

```
<h3> {{counter = counter + 1}} </h3>
```

Comment: Bindings can't contain assignments. This won't work in angular 5 at least and it is also bad practice. I should downvote, but I will let the author update their post.